# Using Frobenius numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

Given $a,b\in\Bbb N$ coprime we have that each $ac+bd$ is unique if $0<c<b$ and $0<d<a$ holds.

Given $a,b\in\Bbb N$ coprime it is **not** true that each $ac+bd$ is unique if $-b<c<b$, $-a<d<a$ and $cd\neq0$ holds.

The number of integers in $$[0,2ab-(a+b)]$$ that get represented by $ac+bd$ when $0<c<b$ and $0<d<a$ holds is $\frac12(a-1)(b-1)-1$ wher $(a-1)(b-1)$ is Frobenius number.

However how many integers in $$[-2ab+(a+b),2ab-(a+b)]$$ get represented by $ac+bd$ if $-b<c<b$, $-a<d<a$ and $cd\neq0$ holds?

Is there a relation to Frobenius numbers?

---

$ac+bd=ac'+bd'$ happens only if $cc',dd'<0$. Also $c'<0\implies d>0$.

Assume $c'<0$.

$$ac+bd=ac'+bd'\iff a(c-c')=b(d'-d)\iff c=c'+kb\wedge d'=ka+d$$ Moreover $$c=c'+b\wedge d'=a+d$$ holds since $$-b<c,c'<b$$ $$-a<d,d'<a$$ $$cd,c'd'\neq0$$ holds.

There are $2a\cdot2b$ pairs of $c,d$.

Pick $c'<0$. Now for every $d'>0$ we have a $c=c'+b$ and $d=d'-a$ such that $ ac+bd=ac'+bd'$ holds. We have $a$ choices for $d'$ and $b$ choices for $a$.

Consequently $4ab-ab=3ab$ different integers in $[-2ab+(a+b),2ab-(a+b)]$ getting represented.

Is my count correct?

Comment: This phenomenon you have noticed is essentially noting that [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) gives a minimal relation between $a$ and $b$. Given that $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $ac + bd = 1$ for some values of $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @kenduna sure but I am asking how many in some bounds. there is no phenomenon here.

Comment: I believe that using Bezout's Identity would be helpful in thinking about this problem. I'm too hungover to work it out at the moment, but that is my intuition. It seems like you could use it as a baseline and think about varying $c,d$ as moving away from the baseline.

Comment: @KenDuna dont think it will work $ac'+bd'=1\implies ac'e+bd'e=e$ where $c'e,b'e$ may not be in bounds I want.